# ZF2 and Oracle stored procedure call with varying IN OUT param length

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, zend-framework2

```
$parameterContainer = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\ParameterContainer();
$parameterContainer->offsetSet('paramName', $someString, $parameterContainer::TYPE_STRING);
```

where $someString is, for example, of length 30.

Now, this param is of "IN OUT" type, and in procedure it's being extended with some additional chars (input length: 30 but outputs 40).

*Note:
I do not even see this procedure code, but after many tests i see that it just appends chars to the initial string with no trimming etc...*

Is simple with pure php (set length the to max possible output length) but in zf2's *Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Oci8\Statement*
oci_bind_by_name() is being called always with -1 as length (so OUT length = IN length = length of initial string), which seems to make it impossible to use with that kind of procedure behavior (getting *ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small*).

Or am I wrong and there IS any possibility (other that not using FW methods or overriding them) to achieve described goal?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Rememeber that $someString is passed as reference so if you send a 30 lenght char you will get another 30 lenght char as maximum.

I recommended you to increase the lenght.

Comment: Hi,As i stated in original question - length of $someString doesn't matter - procedure always append additional chars at the end.

Comment: Usually a define the string variables by this way: $rtrn = str_repeat(' ', 4000);